# File diff against the last commit with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am trying to use JGit to get the differences of a file from the last commit to the most recent uncommitted changes. How can I do this with JGit? (using the command line would be the output of `git diff HEAD`)

Following several discussions ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861881/jgit-cannot-find-a-tutorial-or-simple-example), [link2](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowFileDiff.java)) I come with a piece of code that is able to find the files that are uncommited, but it I cannot get the difference of the files

```
Repository db = new FileRepository("/path/to/git");
Git git = new Git(db);

AbstractTreeIterator oldTreeParser = this.prepareTreeParser(db, Constants.HEAD);

List<DiffEntry> diff = git.diff().setOldTree(oldTreeParser).call();

for (DiffEntry entry : diff) {
    System.out.println("Entry: " + entry + ", from: " + entry.getOldId() + ", to: " + entry.getNewId());
    DiffFormatter formatter = new DiffFormatter(System.out);
    formatter.setRepository(db);
    formatter.format(entry);

}
```

**UPDATE**

This issue was a long time ago. My existing for does display the uncommitted code. The current code that I am using for `prepareTreeParser`, in the context of displaying the difference, is:

```
public void gitDiff() throws Exception {
    Repository db = new FileRepository("/path/to/git" + DEFAULT_GIT);
    Git git = new Git(db);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DiffFormatter formatter = new DiffFormatter( out );
    formatter.setRepository(git.getRepository());
    AbstractTreeIterator commitTreeIterator = prepareTreeParser(git.getRepository(), Constants.HEAD);
    FileTreeIterator workTreeIterator = new FileTreeIterator( git.getRepository() );
    List<DiffEntry> diffEntries = formatter.scan( commitTreeIterator, workTreeIterator );

    for( DiffEntry entry : diffEntries ) {
        System.out.println("DIFF Entry: " + entry + ", from: " + entry.getOldId() + ", to: " + entry.getNewId());
        formatter.format(entry);
        String diffText = out.toString("UTF-8");
        System.out.println(diffText);
        out.reset();
    }
    git.close();
    db.close();

    // This code is untested. It is slighting different for the code I am using in production,
    // but it should be very easy to adapt it for your needs
}
private static AbstractTreeIterator prepareTreeParser(Repository repository, String ref) throws Exception {
    Ref head = repository.getRef(ref);
    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
    RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
    RevTree tree = walk.parseTree(commit.getTree().getId());

    CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeParser = new CanonicalTreeParser();
    ObjectReader oldReader = repository.newObjectReader();
    try {
        oldTreeParser.reset(oldReader, tree.getId());
    } finally {
        oldReader.release();
    }
    return oldTreeParser;
}
```

Comment: The code for `this.prepareTreeParser()` method is missing.

Comment: @PavelLobodinský just updated with the existing code I am using to get the diff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following setup works for me:

```
DiffFormatter formatter = new DiffFormatter( System.out );
formatter.setRepository( git.getRepository() );
AbstractTreeIterator commitTreeIterator = prepareTreeParser( git.getRepository(),  Constants.HEAD );
FileTreeIterator workTreeIterator = new FileTreeIterator( git.getRepository() );
List<DiffEntry> diffEntries = formatter.scan( commitTreeIterator, workTreeIterator );

for( DiffEntry entry : diffEntries ) {
  System.out.println( "Entry: " + entry + ", from: " + entry.getOldId() + ", to: " + entry.getNewId() );
  formatter.format( entry );
}
```

The uncommitted changes are made accessible trough the `FileTreeIterator`. Using `formatter.scan()` instead of the `DiffCommand` has the advantage that the formatter is set up properly to handle the `FileTreeIterator`. Otherwise you will get `MissingObjectException`s as the formatter tries to locate changes from the work tree in the repository.