# JGit: MissingObjectException when diff'ing modified files

Tags: git, jgit, rjgit

I made some changes to a file in a git repository but didn't `git add` it yet.  Then I tried to view the diff using jgit (via [rjgit](https://github.com/repotag/rjgit)).

Without asking for the patch, this works fine:

```rb
> repo = RJGit::Repo.new('/path/to/repo', git_dir: '/path/to/repo/.git')
> RJGit::Porcelain.diff(repo, file_path: 'some_file')
[{:changetype=>"MODIFY",
  :oldpath=>"some_file",
  :newpath=>"some_file",
  :oldmode=>33188,
  :newmode=>33188,
  :score=>0,
  :oldid=>"9ace5cb286c3030f4ce67f30e62e1ae3da6b0152",
  :newid=>"8131e7090f2ff0026149db01a6cc892df8c27793"}]
```

But when I ask to see the patch, I get an exception:

```rb
> repo = RJGit::Repo.new('/path/to/repo', git_dir: '/path/to/repo/.git')
> RJGit::Porcelain.diff(repo, patch: true, file_path: 'some_file')
Java::OrgEclipseJgitErrors::MissingObjectException: Missing blob 8131e7090f2ff0026149db01a6cc892df8c27793
from org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(org/eclipse/jgit/internal/storage/file/WindowCursor.java:170)
org.eclipse.jgit.diff.ContentSource$ObjectReaderSource.open(org/eclipse/jgit/diff/ContentSource.java:145)
org.eclipse.jgit.diff.ContentSource$Pair.open(org/eclipse/jgit/diff/ContentSource.java:282)
org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.open(org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffFormatter.java:1065)
org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.createFormatResult(org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffFormatter.java:993)
org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.format(org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffFormatter.java:698)
```

Jgit is correct--the object doesn't exist:

```sh
$ ls .git/objects/81/31e7090f2ff0026149db01a6cc892df8c27793
ls: cannot access '.git/objects/81/31e7090f2ff0026149db01a6cc892df8c27793': No such file or directory
```

However, `git diff` is able to show me the patch just fine, without the object existing.  If I `git add` the file, it creates the object and even if I then `git reset`, jgit no longer throws the exception since the object now exists.

1) How is `git diff` able to do show a patch for an object that doesn't exist yet?
2) How can I make jgit either show me the patch without creating an object, or create the object without adding the file to the index?

(Note: I found some similar questions at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/268050/ and https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1086495/, but neither one contains a solution.)

**UPDATE**:
I found a solution to my second question ("How can I make jgit either show me the patch without creating an object, or create the object without adding the file to the index?"):

```rb
RJGit::Blob.new_from_string(repo, File.read('some_file'))
```

This creates the object without adding it the file to the index.  This seems less than ideal, as this should be possible without touching the filesystem.

Comment: Objects in a Git repository may be *packed*, in which case there is no `.git/objects/ab/cdef...` file. The object is embedded in a `.git/objects/pack/...` file instead. Presumably anything that pretends to be Git should already be capable of reading pack files, though.

Comment: In JGit, you can diff the working directory with a commit (that's what I understand you want to do) with API from the plumbing layer (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486483/file-diff-against-the-last-commit-with-jgit). Maybe rjgit does not support this or you need to use its lower level API, assuming that there is.